# Draw mesh with GPU

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have got data of Vertex(each vertices) and indices, which i put to GraphicsBuffer. I want to draw mesh using both Buffers.

i found DrawProcedural (..instanced, etc..), but it can draw mesh only with index buffer and size of vertex buffer. (when i used vertexbuffer, it showed me error: "it must have ints")

Dont you know any method, which i can use to draw a mesh (using GPU not CPU) using Vertexbuffer **and** IndexBuffer?

if program is needed, i can send here.

Thank you.
Have a nice day

Comment: It's easier just to use `Mesh`.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html

Comment: i know but i have 500,000 vertices and indexes. using CPU will slow processing and thats my problem.

Comment: _"i know but i have 500,000 vertices and indexes. **using CPU will slow processing** and thats my problem"_ - what makes you think `Mesh` is CPU-only?  If you want to do serious proceduaral stuff take a look at [GPGPU](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/n-body-galaxy-simulation-using-compute-shaders-on-gpgpu-via-unity-3d/)

Comment: i drew it by Mesh and i couldnt even move the scene. :/ and i read many forums why it happends and i found this thing. so i want to try this way too.

Comment: Consider posting a [mcve] so we could spot potential problems.  BTW _["...Generally speaking, aim for no more than 100,000 vertices on mobile. A **PC manages well even with several million vertices**, but it is still good practice to keep this number **as low as possible** through **optimization**..."](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html)_.   If you are re-generating a 500,000 vertice mesh and sending it to the GPU each frame that's not particularly efficient

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret this thread right, it sadly seems like this feature is not fully implemented yet :( https://forum.unity.com/threads/graphicsbuffer-and-mesh.636631/

What I have done for externally generated procedural terrain, is make use of the functions like GetNativeVertexBufferPtr and this way manipulate an existing mesh from a DLL (efectively using a whole mesh as a buffer). This achieves fairly high performance. Maybe you can manage to write the data directly into the mesh this way, without the graphics buffer.

Alternatively, what has been already implemented is rendering from a "ComputeBuffer" via: DrawProceduralIndirect